# Grails run-app FAILED

Tags: grails, gradle

I just installed Grails with sdkman and I am getting this error when I try to run the app. This is the error I get. I just created the app, it is basically empty.

---

| Running application...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':detachedConfiguration18'.

  > Could not find ant-launcher.jar (org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.9.4).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/apache/ant/ant-launcher/1.9.4/ant-launcher-1.9.4.jar
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':detachedConfiguration18'.
      at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$1.collectFiles(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:139)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.doGetFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:516)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:367)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:68)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter$FileCollectionVisitorImpl.visitCollection(AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:133)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitRootElements(AbstractFileCollection.java:234)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitRootElements(CompositeFileCollection.java:185)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:71)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.AbstractNamedFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.buildSnapshots(AbstractNamedFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.java:87)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.AbstractNamedFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.(AbstractNamedFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.java:54)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.InputFilesTaskStateChanges.(InputFilesTaskStateChanges.java:28)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.TaskUpToDateState.(TaskUpToDateState.java:55)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.getStates(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:164)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:79)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:51)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
      at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
      at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
      at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
      at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
      at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
      at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
      at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
      at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
      at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:256)
      at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:253)
      at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
      at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:175)
      at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
      at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:50)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
      at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
      at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
  Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find ant-launcher.jar (org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.9.4).
  Searched in the following locations:
  https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/apache/ant/ant-launcher/1.9.4/ant-launcher-1.9.4.jar
      at org.gradle.internal.resolve.result.DefaultBuildableArtifactResolveResult.notFound(DefaultBuildableArtifactResolveResult.java:27)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$LocateInCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifactFromCache(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:273)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$LocateInCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:257)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.java:64)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository$CachedAccess.resolveArtifact(InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository.java:106)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:121)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(RepositoryChainArtifactResolver.java:66)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.ComponentResolversChain$ArtifactResolverChain.resolveArtifact(ComponentResolversChain.java:103)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactResolver$3.run(CacheLockingArtifactResolver.java:58)
      at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:25)
      at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:190)
      at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:172)
      at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:136)
      at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:199)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:60)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(CacheLockingArtifactResolver.java:56)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(ErrorHandlingArtifactResolver.java:56)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.DefaultArtifactSet$LazyArtifactSource.create(DefaultArtifactSet.java:159)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.DefaultArtifactSet$LazyArtifactSource.create(DefaultArtifactSet.java:146)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultResolvedArtifact.getFile(DefaultResolvedArtifact.java:120)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ResolvedFilesCollectingVisitor.addArtifacts(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:352)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$1.collectFiles(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:134)
      ... 91 more

Comment: If you click that link above in your browser does it download? It does for me, are you behind a firewall or have websense or something similar blocking downloads that aren't initiated by a web browser?

Comment: yeah it downloads. That's why I don't understand what's the actual problem. Any guesses?

Comment: @MikeW. Can I download it manually and make gradle point to it?

Comment: You can, you'll have to put it in your local repo, try again with --stacktrace to see the exact issue first

Comment: I can't paste the full output its longer than 30000 but ill add some of it.